# Is there an embeddings technique to represent multilingual paragraphs?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, word-embedding, bert-language-model, doc2vec

I have a dataset that includes English, Spanish and German documents. I want to represent them using document embeddings techniques to compute their similarities. However, as the documents are in different languages and the length of each one is paragraph-sized, it is difficult to find a pre-trained model (I do not have enough data for training)  .

I found some interesting models like [Sent2Vec](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.04307.pdf) and [LASER](https://medium.com/the-artificial-impostor/multilingual-similarity-search-using-pretrained-bidirectional-lstm-encoder-e34fac5958b0) that also work on multilingual context. However, both of them have been implemented for sentence representation. The question is two folds:

- Is there any model that could be used to represent multilingual paragraphs?
- Is it possible to employ sent2vec (or LASER) to represent paragraphs (I mean to represent each paragraph using an embeddings vector)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found an answer? I'm currently having this problem

Comment: No, I have not.